# jQuery Ketchup validation rule with ajax call inside

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery ketchup validation plugin, which can be found here:
https://github.com/mustardamus/ketchup-plugin

The basic idea behind it binds custom validation events (or rules) to the field in a form, and after focus is lost on the field it triggers that events. If validation rule returns true, it means the field is validated.

I added my custom validation rule:

```
jQuery.ketchup.validation('email_unique', _('Email is being used by another user.'), function (form, el, value) {
            $j.ajax({
                url: Routes.webshop_check_email_uniqueness_path().url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {email: el.val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    // this should always work
                    return true;
                }
            });
    });
```

But this doesn't work, it always returns false. 
I also tried with making my jQuery call synchronous by using: `async: false` but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.ketchup.validation('email_unique', _('Email is being used by another user.'), function (form, el, value) {
        var rtn = false;
        $.ajax({
            url: Routes.webshop_check_email_uniqueness_path().url,
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {email: el.val()},
            success: function(data) {
                // this should always work
                rtn = true;
            }
        });
       return rtn
});
```

Comment: Adding var rtn is the correction. It also requires async: false.

Comment: I found out the same thing but it didn't work as expected. Finally I made a lot more code using some `data` in html elements.